# Parsing a dictionary to retrieve a key in Python 3.6

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

I have a Python dictionary and I am trying to figure out how to get a specific key and value.

Here is the example Python dictionary and I need to retrieve the `category_id` value.

```
lines = [ 
 {'id': 'sub_BUNbsaTbxzrZYW', 'category_id': 'prodcat_xMOTFxgQnA', 'object': 'line_item', 'amount': 9999, 'currency': 'usd', 'description': '1x Yearly (at $99.99)', 'discountable': True, 'livemode': True, 'metadata': {}, 'period': {'start': 1538833681, 'end': 1570369681}, 'plan': {'id': 'Nuts Yearly', 'object': 'plan', 'amount': 10000, 'created': 1498624603, 'currency': 'usd', 'interval': 'year', 'interval_count': 1, 'livemode': False, 'metadata': {}, 'name': 'Nuts Yearly', 'statement_descriptor': None, 'trial_period_days': None}, 'proration': False, 'quantity': 1, 'subscription': None, 'subscription_item': 'si_1B7OqTAQofPy1JZrjB5myHN5', 'type': 'subscription'}, 


 {'id': 'sub_BUNbsaTbxzrZYW', 'category_id': 'prodcat_jbWGPxLNHM', 'object': 'line_item', 'amount': 9999, 'currency': 'usd', 'description': '1x Yearly (at $99.99)', 'discountable': True, 'livemode': True, 'metadata': {}, 'period': {'start': 1538833681, 'end': 1570369681}, 'plan': {'id': 'Nuts Yearly', 'object': 'plan', 'amount': 10000, 'created': 1498624603, 'currency': 'usd', 'interval': 'year', 'interval_count': 1, 'livemode': False, 'metadata': {}, 'name': 'Nuts Yearly', 'statement_descriptor': None, 'trial_period_days': None}, 'proration': False, 'quantity': 1, 'subscription': None, 'subscription_item': 'si_1B7OqTAQofPy1JZrjB5myHN5', 'type': 'subscription'}], 'has_more': False, 'object': 'list', 'url': '/v1/invoices/in_1Bg1FZAQofPy1JZrLNlHERmz/lines'}]
```

I am able to get the data using:

```
cat_id = []
for i in lines:
    for k, v in i.items():
        if k == 'category_id':
            cat_id.append(v)
```

How can I make my code more efficient for this scenario?

Comment: Don't you just want `[line['category_id'] for line in lines]` (search for "list comprehension")? It doesn't seem like there's any point iterating over the dictionary giving that efficient lookup by key is **exactly what they're optimised for**. Also this *isn't* parsing and you have a *list* of dictionaries.

Comment: Does your code not work? It looks like it should work. Could use some optimisation, but that's what CodeReview stackexchange is for.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you! That is a lot cleaner :) I was even able to add a condition so that list only got created if it matched a specific id. Appreciate the help. Also, thanks for the clarification on the wording.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak The code did work. Thanks for letting me know about CodeReview.

Answer (score 1):

Just pick element from dictionary:

```
cat_id = []
for line in lines:
    cat_id.append(line['category_id'])
```

or

```
cat_id = [line['category_id'] for line in lines]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that each entry of your dicts contains that category, you can do it faster this way :

```
cat_id = []
for i in lines:
    cat_id.append(i.get("category_id"))
```

For any entries that have no 'category_id' a 'None' will be saved to the list