# Parsing list of dictionaries in a dictionary to retrieve a specific key's value from each dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I got a JSON response and converted it to a python dictionary using `json.loads()`. So the dictionary looks like this:

```
{u'body': u'[{"id":"1","entity":"zone","status":"PROCESSING","url":null,"createdOn":"2019-10-11T05:49:11Z"},{"id":"2","entity":"floor","status":"FAILED","url":null,"createdOn":"2019-10-11T05:49:15Z"},{"id":"3","entityType":"apartment","status":"SUCCESS","url":null,"createdOn":"2019-10-11T05:49:18Z"}]',u'isBase64Encoded': False, u'statusCode': 200}
```

I named this as `testStatusList`. I want to retrieve the value of `"status"` key of every dictionary inside `"body"`. I was able to retrieve the `"body"` by giving `body = testStatusList['body']`. Now, the dictionary looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "entityType": "zone",
        "status": "PROCESSING",
        "url": null,
        "createdOn": "2019-03-07T12:47:10Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "entityType": "floor",
        "status": "FAILED",
        "url": null,
        "createdOn": "2019-08-19T16:46:13Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "entityType": "apartment",
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "url": null,
        "createdOn": "2019-08-19T16:46:13Z"
    }
]
```

I tried out this solution [[Parsing a dictionary to retrieve a key in Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104644/parsing-a-dictionary-to-retrieve-a-key-in-python-3-6][1])

```
testStatusList= json.loads(status_response['Payload'].read())
    body = testStatusList['body']
    status =[]
    for b in body:
       for k,v in b.items():
           if k == 'status':
               status.append(v)
```

but I keep getting `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'`. Is there a different method to get items for unicode objects?

So I basically want to retrieve all the statuses i.e., PROCESSING, FAILED AND SUCCESS so that I can put an 'if' condition to display appropriate messages when something failed for that particular "id". I am very unsure about my approach as I am totally new to Python. Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

body is still a (unicode) string in your top blob. Use `json.loads` again on that string:

```
body = """[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "entityType": "zone",
        "status": "PROCESSING",
        "url": null,
        "createdOn": "2019-03-07T12:47:10Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "entityType": "floor",
        "status": "FAILED",
        "url": null,
        "createdOn": "2019-08-19T16:46:13Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "entityType": "apartment",
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "url": null,
        "createdOn": "2019-08-19T16:46:13Z"
    }
]"""


import json
body = json.loads(body)
status =[]
for b in body:
   for k,v in b.items():
       if k == 'status':
           status.append(v) 
print(status)
```

Result:

> ['PROCESSING', 'FAILED', 'SUCCESS']

Comment: Okay that worked for me! I didn't know I had to load the body again. Thanks!